# Horizontal translation of integrable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be some Banach space. For $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ let $\tau_a\colon E^{(\mathbb{R}^n)}\to E^{(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ be the translation given by $$(\tau_a\varphi)(x):=\varphi(x-a),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\, \varphi\in E^{(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

I want to show that, for $p\in[1,\infty[$, we have $\lim_{a\to 0}\Vert \tau_af-f\Vert_p=0$ for all $f\in L_p(\mathbb{R}^n,\lambda_n, E)$, and that if $\lim_{a\to 0}\Vert \tau_af-f\Vert_\infty =0$ we have some bounded, unformly continuous map $g\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to E$ such that $f=g$ $\lambda_n$-a.e. I don't know how.

(I know that, for $p\in [1,\infty]$, $\tau_a$ is a topological automorphism of $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n,\lambda_n, E)$ with $\Vert\tau_a\Vert= 1$. Does this help?)

Comment: What do you mean by $E^{\mathbb R^n}$? Oh, I see, it's the set of $E$-valued functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$. Maybe it's a good idea to write that explicitly.

Comment: This result depends on the density of $C_0(\mathbb R^n; E)$ into $L^p$. (Here $C_0$ denotes continuous functions vanishing at infinity). I like how this is proved in the book "Analysis" of Lieb and Loss. Of course, there $E$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, so you will have to extrapolate from there.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Exactly, thank you for doing that then (writing it out). The question is an exercise from a pretty self-contained book and the density of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n,E)$ is not mentioned. However, I know that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n, E)$, the set of functions of compact support, is dense in $L_p$ (for $p\neq\infty$). Will this help? Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, that's the same. The idea is that what you want to prove is true for uniformly continuous functions. You then need to extend the result by density. Incidentally, note that spaces of continuous functions are not dense in L^\infty. That's why the text requires that p\in[1, \infty)